# Vaadin Tab selects wrong tab

Tags: tabs, vaadin7

I have this little piece of code which aims to set the tab content and select it. The contents go to the right tab, but somehow the selected tab is a different one:

```
private void setTabContent(Tab target, Component content,
            String permission) {
        Layout l = (Layout) target.getComponent();
        l.removeAllComponents();
        l.addComponent(content);
        right.setSelectedTab(target);
    }
```

In the example right is a TabSheet. I suspect there's a bug somewhere but it seems it's on Vaadin side. I doubt no one has seen this if that was the case.

Using Vaadin 7.7.7. Source can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/javydreamercsw/validation-manager). It's on the test-management branch. To trigger it just login (admin, admin as credentials) then click on any node on the tree on the left. The content is sent to the Main tab, but the Tester tab is highlighted instead.

Comment: Code looks OK. You should try to make a minimal example that reproduces the error.

Comment: I did the demo project and everything worked fine. Should be a local bug. Looking into it. Thanks!

Comment: For some reason if I take out the content modification piece in the original code it selects the right one.

Comment: Finally found an issue. After that code I was making it not visible with some criteria. Still wonder why it still shows in the tab sheet.